# how to use case to do multiple insert in a table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using a case like this in stored procedure.

```
BEGIN
         FOREACH abc IN array abcarray 
       LOOP         
            case abc
when abc1 then INSERT 1 into table a;
when abc2 then INSERT 2 into table a;
else
                --do nothing
end case;
        
                
END LOOP;
```

Is this the proper way to use case if the requirement is to insert both 1 and 2 in the table or should i try something else?

Comment: you can try using the MERGE-Statement with different when-clauses and conditions

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for that. You can embed a CASE expression into a SELECT that acts as the source for the INSERT

```
insert into table_a (some_column)
select case 
         when abc = 'abc1' then 1 
         when abc = 'abc2' then 2
       end
from unnest(abcarray) as x(abc);
```